# Gtk3 Video capture Drag and Drop does not work

Tags: python, python-3.x, drag-and-drop, gtk3

I have a program written in Python 3 and using Drag and Drop. I want to make Video tutorials. But when the Video capture is working, Drop fails. The capture program seems to intercept some signal.

I have tried several programs (Jing and others) with the same result. I am testing with a very simple Python script. When the capture is working, the lines which normally indicate the drop location do not appear. The get_data and the received_data functions are not launched.
I am in Windows 8. I have not tested in Linux.

Below, my python3 test code.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

# example treeviewdnd.py modified

from gi.repository import Gtk, Gdk, Pango, GObject

class TreeViewDnDExample:

    TARGETS = [
        ('MY_TREE_MODEL_ROW', Gtk.TargetFlags.SAME_WIDGET, 0),
        ('text/plain', 0, 1),
        ('TEXT', 0, 2),
        ('STRING', 0, 3),
        ]
    # close the window and quit
    def delete_event(self, widget, event, data=None):
        Gtk.main_quit()
        return False

    def clear_selected(self, button):
        selection = self.treeview.get_selection()
        model, iter = selection.get_selected()
        if iter:
            model.remove(iter)
        return

    def __init__(self):
        # Create a new window
        self.window = Gtk.Window()

        self.window.set_title("URL Cache")

        self.window.set_size_request(200, 200)

        self.window.connect("delete_event", self.delete_event)

        self.scrolledwindow = Gtk.ScrolledWindow()
        self.vbox = Gtk.VBox()
        self.hbox = Gtk.HButtonBox()
        self.vbox.pack_start(self.scrolledwindow, True, True, 0)
        self.vbox.pack_start(self.hbox, False, True, 0)
        self.b0 = Gtk.Button('Clear All')
        self.b1 = Gtk.Button('Clear Selected')
        self.hbox.pack_start(self.b0, True, True, 0)
        self.hbox.pack_start(self.b1, True, True, 0)

        # create a liststore with one string column to use as the model
        self.liststore = Gtk.ListStore(str)
        for a in "abcd" :
            self.liststore.append([a])

        # create the TreeView using liststore
        self.treeview = Gtk.TreeView(self.liststore)

       # create a CellRenderer to render the data
        self.cell = Gtk.CellRendererText()

        # create the TreeViewColumns to display the data
        self.tvcolumn = Gtk.TreeViewColumn('URL', self.cell, text=0)

        # add columns to treeview
        self.treeview.append_column(self.tvcolumn)
        self.b0.connect_object('clicked', Gtk.ListStore.clear, self.liststore)
        self.b1.connect('clicked', self.clear_selected)
        # make treeview searchable
        self.treeview.set_search_column(0)

        # Allow sorting on the column
        self.tvcolumn.set_sort_column_id(0)

        # Allow enable drag and drop of rows including row move
        self.treeview.enable_model_drag_source( Gdk.ModifierType.BUTTON1_MASK,
                                                self.TARGETS,
                                                Gdk.DragAction.DEFAULT|
                                                Gdk.DragAction.MOVE)
        self.treeview.enable_model_drag_dest(self.TARGETS,
                                             Gdk.DragAction.DEFAULT)
        self.treeview.drag_dest_add_text_targets()
        self.treeview.drag_source_add_text_targets()

        self.treeview.connect("drag_data_get", self.drag_data_get_data)
        self.treeview.connect("drag_data_received",
                              self.drag_data_received_data)

        self.scrolledwindow.add(self.treeview)
        self.window.add(self.vbox)
        self.window.show_all()

    def drag_data_get_data(self, treeview, context, selection, target_id,
                           etime):
        print("drag get data")
        treeselection = treeview.get_selection()
        model, iter = treeselection.get_selected()
        data = bytes(model.get_value(iter, 0), "utf-8")
        selection.set(selection.get_target(), 8, data)

    def drag_data_received_data(self, treeview, context, x, y, selection,
                                info, etime):
        print("received")


def main():
    Gtk.main()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    treeviewdndex = TreeViewDnDExample()
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

Since I didn't find an answer to the problem in Windows, the solution was to launch the program on a Linux machine where video capture programs does not present the same effect. It was even possible to be connected to the Linux machine with VNCViewer, and make the capture in the Windows box. For demonstration purposes, it is sufficient. 
But I am still wondering what prevents Gtk-Windows to receive the drop event.